# GUI app displays for Mac

Tags: macos, vim, ssh

I just recently switched over from using a PC to a Mac. To do my programming assignments I would usually SSH onto the school server using Putty and XMing to create a visual interface when I opened apps (like GVIM). On the Mac, I can conveniently use the terminal for the same effect, however I don't yet know how to acquire the same GUI interface when I open apps that I had through XMing on my PC. I downloaded XQuartz, which contains X11, but gvim still won't open up, it will tell me the display can't be opened and opens vim on the terminal instead. I have XQuartz running while I'm doing this, and I have tried this both on the Terminal.app as well as on the XQuartz provided terminal, but no luck. Anyone know a way to get this working? Thanks in advance!

Edit: So I got it to open, but I'm having editing problems. I find every time I open gvim, same file or not I need to do ":set backspace=2" in order to delete text old or new. Is there anything I can do so i don't need to do this every time? I can't find a vimrc file, and this is a server I'm sshing into.

Comment: I have no idea if this will help, or is even possible on a Mac, but maybe you need to type 'xhost +' in Terminal to permit connections to your X11 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X11-forwarding is ***very*** simple:

1. Open Terminal.app
2. Connect to your school server with the `-Y` parameter:

   ```
   $ ssh -Y username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
   ```
3. You are now logged in your school server and you can run remote GUI applications as if they were local:

   ```
   $ gvim filename
   ```

You don't even need to start X11 yourself.

Comment: I got it working with the -X option, whats the difference between x and y?

Comment: Both enable X11 forwarding. `-X` is AFAIK more secure than `-Y`.